# What's the right way to one-hot-encode a categorical tuple in Tensorflow/Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I want to create a neural network that takes a categorical tuple as input and passes its one-hot-encoded value to its layers.

For example, assuming that the tuple value limits were `(2, 2, 3)`, I need a preprocessing layer that transforms the following three-dimensional list of values:

```
[
  (1, 0, 0),
  (0, 0, 1),
  (1, 1, 2),
]
```

Into the following one-dimensional tensor:

```
[
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
]
```

Does such a function exist?

Comment: your example is definitely not clear, first of all, there are not 3D in the first array, and second of all, the (2,2,3) does not make the desired output, please provide more informations

Comment: Will your *batched* input have uneven number of tuples, like `[[(1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1)], [(1, 1, 2)]]`, or will it always have the exact same number of tuples, like `[[(1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1)], [(0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 2)]]`?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia The final size of the output is 2 * 2 * 3 = 12. `(2, 2, 3)` is the maximum size of each dimension.

Comment: @bui Does it make a difference? I can make it work for both cases.

Comment: If the number of tuples is not the same for each sample, then the input will be a `RaggedTensor` instead of a normal `Tensor`. The former supports fewer ops than the latter, but fortunately in your case each sample has a well-defined shape and can be converted back to a normal tensor with no padding.

Comment: in your question: _tuple value limits were `(2, 2, 3)`_, now _`(2, 2, 3)` is the maximum size of each dimension_... you need to clarify how you wan the transformation to be done, and what is what

Comment: at the moment I believe that the explanation for the 12 is that for the first number you need a single bit to describe the class, for the second bit you need one bit, and for the third one 2 bits, thus 4 bit per tuple, and for 3 tuples you thus need 12 bits, please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that this custom layer operates on a batch having varied number of tuples per sample. For example, an input batch may be

```
[[(1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 2)],
 [(1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 2)]]
```

and the desired output tensors would be

```
[[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
```

Since the samples can be of uneven sizes, the batch needs to be converted to `tf.RaggedTensor` (instead of normal `Tensor`) before being fed to the layer. However, the following solution works with both `tf.Tensor` and `tf.RaggedTensor` as input.

```
class FillOneLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, shape, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.shape = shape
    
    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        num_samples = inputs.nrows() if isinstance(inputs, tf.RaggedTensor) else tf.shape(inputs)[0]
        num_samples = tf.cast(num_samples, tf.int32)
        ret = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=num_samples, dynamic_size=False)
        for i in range(num_samples):
            sample = inputs[i]
            sample = sample.to_tensor() if isinstance(sample, tf.RaggedTensor) else sample
            updates_shape = tf.shape(sample)[:-1]
            tmp = tf.zeros(self.shape)
            tmp = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(tmp, sample, tf.ones(updates_shape))
            ret = ret.write(i, tf.reshape(tmp, (-1,)))

        return ret.stack()
```

Output for normal input tensor

```
>>> a = tf.constant([[(1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 2)],
                     [(1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2)]])
>>> FillOneLayer((2,2,3))(a)

<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 12), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Output for ragged tensor

```
>>> a = tf.ragged.constant([[(1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 2)], 
                            [(1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1)]])
>>> FillOneLayer((2,2,3))(a)

<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 12), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
```

The solution also works when you decorate `call()` with `tf.function`, which is usually what happens when you call `fit` on a model whom this layer is a member of. In that case, to avoid graph retracing, you should ensure that all batches are of the same type, i.e., either all `RaggedTensor` or all `Tensor`.

Comment: I tried to manually implement a solution to what I wanted to do and I realised that the problem is actually not well defined. I'm accepting this answer since it taught me about ragged tensors, which could help in a similar problem!